# How can i start node script from my react-app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, arduino, led

What is the easiest way to launch a node.js script from a react-app by using a  button?

I've a simple app with two buttons - using Material.io

```
export default function ButtonsMenu() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
    <Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper style={styles.Paper}>
                <Button onClick={activeLights} variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
                    ON
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={inactiveLights}variant="contained" color="secondary" className={classes.button}>
                    OFF
                </Button>
            </Paper>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    );
```

I also have an Arduino with led stripe that i wrote a node.js code for. 
How can i run it from the browser?

I know that i need a node server and a client, but need some help what should i do next.

I would appreciate any github repository etc.

Comment: Just an idea, maybe you need to create a REST route that when called will make the server execute the script you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, ReactJs is for fornt using, but instead make an API call to a node js server, even the browser will block you from calling local commands